# labels percent in ggvis R

Tags: r, ggvis

Is there any option in ggvis to show percent value in y-axis like `labels = percent` in `scale_y_continuous` in `ggplot2` using `library(scales)`?

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, number = runif(10,0,1))
ggplot(df, aes(id, number))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(label = percent)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format = "%"` in a call to `add_axis`:

```
df %>% ggvis(~id, ~number) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("y", format = "%")
```

---

[image]

---

More information on `d3` formatting options is available [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting).